# uWSGI writes log as root

Tags: uwsgi

I have following `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = myuser
gid = myuser
master = true
daemonize = /path-to-log/uwsgi.log
...
```

I run uwsgi in `rc.local`. I can see workers run as `myuser`, I can see uwsgi switches to `myuser` in log and I'm assuming `myuser` will also be owner of `uwsgi.log`. But `root` is owner of `uwsgi.log`.

How could I set owner of `uwsgi.log`? It's for convenience - I'd like to see log without sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(from `uwsgi --help`):

`--logto2` (log to specified file or udp address after privileges drop)

(or the similar `--daemonize2` if you want to daemonize)

alternatively

`--logfile-chown` (chown logfiles)

Finally remember you can call custom functions at the various server stages:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Hooks.html